# DeleteAll method in abstract, generic DAO

Tags: generics, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm having a abstract, generic DAO class, from which all other DAO classes inherit from, defined as `public abstract class JpaDAO<K, E> implements IDAO<K, E>`, which defines methods like `persist(E entity)`, `remove(E entity)`, `List<E> findAll()` and so on.

The class has the following class variables and constructor:

```
protected Class<E> entityClass;
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "umPU")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public JpaDAO() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}
```

How to implement a method `public void removeAll()`, which removes all persisted entities?

Comment: That will be used almost never. But it's simple: call findAll(), iterate on all the entities, and remove them.

Comment: I need it to clear up the database after every integration test. So there's no other solution than iterating trough all of them?

Comment: You can use a JPQL delete query, but that won't apply the cascading options. If a method is only used by tests, it shouldn't be partof the production code. Put that in the test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JB Nizet is right, methods which delete all entries will not be used in production thus, **should not be part of the production code**. Iterating through all entries to delete them is acceptable for integration testing, because the performance is more or less irrelevant in that case.